# How to create PHP arrays as Python 3 dictionaries?

Tags: php, python, arrays

My problem is simple. I want to collect images which not contain alt tag.

So, I can add to array images' srcs using `file_get_contents('url');` also alts. Yet I want to add images' srcs with alts. in the same index.

I do not want create this:

```
$arr = ('src', 'alt', 'src', 'alt'...);
```

I want to create this (Dictionary example from python 3):

```
dict = {'img1': {'src': 'src1', 'alt': 'alt1'}, 'img2': {'src': 'src2', 'alt': 'alt2'}}...
```

Should I do this with this method? Yet I need more value fiddle.

```
array(
    img1 => src1,
    img2 => src2,
    img3 => src3,
    ...
)
```

Or it must be like that?

```
array(
    src1 => alt1,
    src2 => alt2,
    src3 => alt3,
    ...
)
```

My function is like that. So, how to convert this python 3 dictionary to PHP? I'm confused really.

```
function get_image_src(){
      $image_element = $this -> doc -> getElementsByTagName('img');
      $image_src_array = array();

      foreach($image_element as $item){
        array_push($image_src_array, $item -> getAttribute('src'));
      }

      return $image_src_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. Dictionaries in Python are like associative arrays in PHP. Why not use an associative array of an associative array?

```
dict = array(
      img1 => array('src' => src1, 'alt'=> alt1),
      img2 => array('src' => src2, 'alt'=> alt2),
      ...,
)
```

Comment: You got me right. How could I not think of that. It works, thank you so much!